# Alternative to std::next

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm working on a C++ code where the compiler version supports the std::next() command, but I'm migrating this code to work on a system where the compiler does not support C++11, and I need to migrate a part of the code that uses std::next, what is the best alternative for this?

The code that I need to migrate is:

```
uint32_t getUint32(uint32_t position, vector<uint8_t> data)
{
    auto it = next(data.cbegin(), position);
    ...
}
```

Comment: See "[possible implementation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) (namespace `std` assumed):

```
vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator it = data.begin();
advance(it, position);
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you can implement your own `next` function by mimicking the [possible implementation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next):*

```
template<class T>
T mynext(T it, typename std::iterator_traits<T>::difference_type n = 1) {
    std::advance(it, n);
    return it;
}
```

* <sup>Everything in this code is C++03 compliant. If you go with this implementation you should [properly attribute](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:FAQ#What_can_I_do_with_the_material_on_this_site.3F) the [cppreference source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next).</sup>